# Powershell ForEach-Object {Start-Job -Scriptblock} not populating variables

Tags: powershell

Here is my code, it works and creates a job for each computer in the OU but does not populate the $Computer variable in my script block causing this to fail.

I am sure I am missing something small since I have never created jobs before in Powershell but after working on this for an hour or two I have been unable to figure out what I am missing.

```
#Gets all workstations that need to have software installed, if you don't want to uninstall all of the software from you will need to use a text document and Get-Content
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Workstation Test,OU=Workstations,OU=Workstations,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM" | Select DNSHostName -ExpandProperty DNSHostname


$Computer
#Use Get-WMIObject to find the IdentifyingNumber
$Computers | ForEach-Object {Start-Job -Name "$Uninstall" -ScriptBlock {(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_product -ComputerName $Computer -Filter {IdentifyingNumber LIKE '{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C2410B}'}).uninstall()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$computer` you need to use `$_`.

$_ represents the current item in the pipeline.

Alternatively you could do:

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_product -Filter {IdentifyingNumber LIKE '{CD95F661-A5C4-44F5-A6AA-ECDD91C2410B}'}).uninstall()} }
```

Here you continue to use $Computer inside the foreach as it now gets populated with each item in the collection.

Also FYI your `$computer` line above the ForEach-Object is currently unnecessary (it's just outputting an empty variable, unless you've already populated it elsewhere).

Edit: per comments I also noticed that the start-job seemed redundant as -computername was being used on the wmi cmdlet. Invoke-command is preferred as it uses winrm, so I've modified it as such in my code above.

Comment: The reason that existed is I copied it off an old script I wrote and I just put that in place so I could see which computer the current foreach loop is working on.

Comment: It appears neither of those work. When I take my original script and modify the $Computer to be $_ I still get the error.

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: I have this script running properly as a Foreach loop but it is very slow, I want to run them in parallel so I am trying to use jobs. Currently the "Select DNSHostname" works properly.

Comment: If you want to run in parallel I think you need invoke-command -asjob instead. You'll need to also read up on receive-job for how to collect the results at the end.

Comment: And I think you'll want to pass $computers to the command rather than using a foreach.

Comment: Although also it seems from PS v3 onwards foreach has a -parallel parameter so you could try that too.

Comment: Issue as in its slow? Are you using -asjob ?

Comment: I think the issue of running jobs in parallel probably would be best answered in a new question with your revised code.

Comment: I just noticed that you are using -computername on get-wmiobject not on the start-job command. I think that makes start-job redundant. I'll revise my answer moving it to the start-job